# Expected identifier or "(" on Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: c, xcode, macos, object

on the line " int RandomA, RandomB" I keep on getting an error. The error says Expected identifier or "(". The same error also pop up between the struct card and the name of the cards. I'm not sure how to fix it. This is my first time asking a question on this website. I'm using mac osx application command line tool.

main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct card {
    char* name;
    char* suit;
    int value;
};


void shuffle(struct card* deck){
    // Seed the random number generator
    srandom(time (NULL ) );
    int i = 0;
    int randomA, randomB;
    struct card tempCard;

    do {
        // Generate 2 random numbers to determine which cards to swap
        randomA = random() % 52;
        randomB = random() % 52;

        // Swap slots A and B
        tempCard = deck[randomA];
        deck[randomA] = deck[randomB];
        deck[randomB] = tempCard;

        // Increment the counter
        ++i;
    }
    while (i<1000000);

}

void printDeck(struct card* deck){
    // Print out the shuffled deck
    int i=0;
    while (i<52) {
        if (deck[i].value == 1) {
            printf("The ace of %s is great!\n", deck[i].suit);
        }
        else {
            switch (deck[i].value){
                case 11:
                    printf("A Jack of all trades (%s)\n",deck[i].suit);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    printf("A Queen of the castle (%s)\n",deck[i].suit);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    printf("The King of the world (%s)\n",deck[i].suit);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("The card is %s of %s\n", deck[i].name,deck[i].suit);
                    break;
            }

        }

        i++;

    }
}





        int main(int argc, const char * argv[]);
{


    struct card deck[] =

    {

    {"ace", "spades", 1}, {"two", "spades", 2}, {"three", "spades", 3},
    {"four", "spades", 4}, {"five", "spades", 5}, {"six", "spades", 6},
    {"seven", "spades", 7}, {"eight", "spades", 8}, {"nine", "spades", 9},
    {"ten", "spades", 10}, {"jack", "spades", 11}, {"queen", "spades", 12},
    {"king", "spades", 13},
    {"ace", "clubs", 1}, {"two", "clubs", 2}, {"three", "clubs", 3},
    {"four", "clubs", 4}, {"five", "clubs", 5}, {"six", "clubs", 6},
    {"seven", "clubs", 7}, {"eight", "clubs", 8}, {"nine", "clubs", 9},
    {"ten", "clubs", 10}, {"jack", "clubs", 11}, {"queen", "clubs", 12},
    {"king", "clubs", 13},
    {"ace", "hearts", 1}, {"two", "hearts", 2}, {"three", "hearts", 3},
    {"four", "hearts", 4}, {"five", "hearts", 5}, {"six", "hearts", 6},
    {"five", "hearts", 7}, {"eight", "hearts", 8}, {"nine", "hearts", 9},
    {"ten", "hearts", 10}, {"jack", "hearts", 11}, {"queen", "hearts", 12},
    {"king", "hearts", 13},
    {"ace", "diamonds", 1}, {"two", "diamonds", 2}, {"three", "diamonds", 3},
    {"four", "diamonds", 4}, {"five", "diamonds", 5}, {"six", "diamonds", 6},
    {"seven", "diamonds", 7}, {"eight", "diamonds", 8}, 
    {"nine", "diamonds", 9}, {"ten", "diamonds", 10}, {"jack", "diamonds", 11}, 
        {"queen", "diamonds", 12},{"king", "diamonds", 13}};






// Run the function to shuffle the deck
        shuffle(deck);

        // Print the deck
        printDeck(deck);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you do have a semicolon at the end of your main function declaration

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  /* -------> */ ; /* <------- */
```

Followed by `{`, which opens up a scope outside of a context...